# Responsive links

Tags: html, css

I have a link on [this page](https://4309.co.uk) which isn't working in desktop view but works on mobile. Is there some kind of responsive issue which would stop it working?

I applied css:

```
a:hover[href="https://
adsler.co.uk"] {color:red 
!important;} 
a:active[href="https://
adsler.co.uk"] {color:red}
```

The html is:

```
<div class="designn"><a  
href="https://adsler.co.uk">
design</a></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: u covered it using z-index:3 on e-letter   >>> here >>> @media (min-width: 768px)
.e {
    z-index: 3;
}

Comment: the class "e" have z-index of 3 , which is stopping the link from clicking it. To fix this give z-index:4 to class "designn"

Comment: @oleevier ah, can I give the link a z index to supercede the e x index

Comment: yes u can change z-index for destop for link tag and u will have access to link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class "e" have z-index of 3 , which is stopping the link from clicking it. To fix this give z-index:4 to class "designn"

```
.designn {
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 350px;
    left: 38px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    z-index: 4; /* added newly */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the red e is above the design link due to z-index being 3 when device width is 768px or more. A quick solution would be adding a z-index value higher than 3 in designn.

Answer (score 0):

u covered it using z-index:3 on e-letter

```
@media (min-width: 768px) .e { z-index: 3; }
```

u can use z-index: -1 for example and u will have access to

Comment: Thanks. Gave you an up vote but doesn't show because I don't have enough points